# Django, getting url parameter into view

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have a `company` model, each instance of which has a foreign_key named `admin` to a user.

I am writing a view to allow company admins to administer their companies:

`urls.py`:

```
path('admin/crn=<company_spec_url>', CompanyAdminView.as_view(), name="CompanyAdminView"),`
```

`views.py`:

```
class CompanyAdminView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'company_admin.html'

    def test_func(self):
        company = Company.objects.filter(crn=context['company_spec_url'])[0]
        return company.admin == self.user

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['company'] = Company.objects.filter(crn=context['company_spec_url'])[0]
        context['announcements'] = CompanyAnnouncement.objects.filter(company__crn=context['company_spec_url'])
        return context
```

The `get_context_data` bit is working fine, the issue is in the `test_func`. Clearly only the company's admin should be allowed to administer a company, so I am trying to get the  into the `test_func`, in order to test against it.

The code in `test_func` does not currently work, because it does not have access to `context`. Is it best practice to: Call `super().get_context_data` once, and make `context` a global variable so that it can be accessed from `test_func` - Call `super().get_context_data` twice, once in `get_context_data` and once in `test_func`, or something else entirely?

I've tried looking at the GET dict in the request, but it's empty. I could just parse the url within `test_func` to get the parameter myself, but it doesn't seem like the 'correct' way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *positional* and *named* parameters are stored in `self.args` and `self.kwargs` respectively, so you can access it with:

```
class CompanyAdminView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, TemplateView):

    # ...

    def test_func(self):
        company = Company.objects.filter(crn=self.kwargs['company_spec_url'])[0]
        return company.admin == self.user
```

Note that the above can be tricky: here if multiple companies have the same `crn`, then you will let a (possibly random) order decide what company you pick, and whether that `admin` is the `self.user`. Furthermore it will here result in two queries.

```
class CompanyAdminView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, TemplateView):

    # ...

    def test_func(self):
        return Company.objects.filter(
            crn=self.kwargs['company_spec_url']
            admin=self.user
        ).exists()
```

With the above we check if there is a `Company` that has as `crn` the parameter in the URL, and `self.user` as `admin`.

Comment: Thanks for this. The crn is actually unique, but the second option is much better, as it catches the case in which the given crn doesn't exist. Thank you!